# Is it possible to have a variable increase using the game logic editor?

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine, logic-bricks, properties

For a game I'm making, I need the speed an object moves increase until it reaches a set amount. If this can be achieved just by using the logic editor that would be brilliant but I know a bit of the Python bge so that would be fine.
Also just out of interest, is it possible to do this on, for example, the camera's orthographic scale (or other properties)?

Also, I might have explained this badly, so let me rephrase: when the game is started, I want an object to gradually speed up until it reaches a certain speed. At this point, I want the object to keep moving at the same speed.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Speed is an attribute of an object rather than a variable. A property is more acting like a variable. Unfortunately what you want to do in your example requires some Python knowledge. But you might be happy by looking at the Physics tab/Physics panel. There are two Velocity parameters: Minimum and Maximum. You can set the maximum and apply any force you like = speed is capped. It caps any speed of that object. (Do not ask me why there is a minimum.)

Comment: @Monster would you like to put that last part down as an answer? also, nice to see you here at SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be happy by looking at the Physics tab/Physics panel.

There are two Velocity parameters: Minimum and Maximum. You can set the maximum and apply any force you like = speed is capped. It caps any speed of that object. 
[image]

(Do not ask me why there is a minimum.)

The downside is, this counts for all motions.